# What happened to the white Ka'kari?

Tags: night-angel-trilogy

At the end of the Night Angel trilogy,

> Khali moves from the desicated corpse of Trace, into Elene, and is then killed with Curoch. Elene dies shortly thereafter.

Unquestionably

> when within Elene

Khali had the white Ka'kari, but what happened to it after that?

[The night angel wiki](http://nightangel.wikia.com/wiki/Ka%27kari#White_Ka.27kari) suggests that it was destroyed with Curoch when Kali was killed but I didn't see any indication of this in the book.

**Are there any definite statements, either quotes from books, or word of god (quotes from the author)
as to what happened to it?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Brent Weeks has left the question of the fate of the white Ka'kari ***deliberately ambiguous***, it seem;

[image]

I guess we'll have to wait a while to find out what happened to it. My gut instinct says that it survived (somehow) or he'd have just said "***yes***".

Comment: Nice work, over 14 months since question asked, but then when word from god arrived, <6hours before it shows up here. Top Notch

Comment: @Oxinabox - Answerguesser401 is ***my*** twitter alter-ego :-) I was trolling through the unanswered questions and spotted that the author has a twitter account. Post, response, repost to SE. Simple really.

Comment: I have attempted to coax additional information out of him, but to [no avail](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GkyL8.png)

Comment: Well then that *also* is great work. Of effort rathr than of luck/memory.